# Create custom cache drive in laravel 5.8 given error "Driver [aerospike] is not supported."

Tags: laravel-5, aerospike

I wanted to create a custom cache driver using aerospike.

I have followed the instruction given in the document:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/cache#adding-custom-cache-drivers

```php
Cache::extend('aerospike', function ($app) {
            $config = $app['config'];
            $server = $config['cache.stores.aerospike.servers'];

            $aerospike = new \Aerospike($server);

            $store = new AerospikeStore($aerospike, $config['cache.prefix'], $config['cache.stores.aerospike.namespace']);

            return Cache::repository($store);
        });
```

also created the AerospikeStore file.

When run `php artisan serve`  it always says :

> In CacheManager.php line 109:
>   Driver [aerospike] is not supported.

Comment: Did you add a package that adds `Aerospike` as a cache driver. did you configure this in its own config file or in `config/cache.php`?

Comment: @mike, I have created own config file. and also try with the cache.php